# Use Python to run a .exe file in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-prompt, openmdao

I am trying to integrate an existing program into a developing Python 2.7 script. Currently the program can be successfully run by typing the following in the command prompt:

```
     `C:\wisdem\plugins\JacketSE\src\jacketse\SubDyn\bin\SubDyn_Win32.exe C:\wisdem\plugins\JacketSE\src\jacketse\SubDyn\CertTest\Test04_TrialD3.txt`
```

This is all one line; the .txt file contains inputs needed by the .exe file. I have tried using both `os.system("C:\wisdem\plugins\...)` and

`subprocess.Popen("C:\wisdem\plugins\...", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()`

to do this, but neither one is working. Also, I need the command prompt's outputs to be printed Python. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Think about what `"\b"` represents. Use a raw string for the command, e.g. `p = subprocess.Popen(r"C:\wisdem\plugins\...", ...)`. Also, don't use `shell=True`. Don't use a pipe for `stdin` or `stderr` if you're not using them.  Leave them as is or pass a file descriptor for the null device, e.g. `fd_null = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)`. If you do pipe more than one standard file, then use the `communicate()` method to avoid the possibility of deadlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
print os.popen(r'''echo "hello"''').read()
```

I would suggest putting the full command within the triple quotes, and attempting. This will execute the command, and then print the output.

Using a String literal with prefix `r` should help with any weird escape character issues you are experiencing.

Please note that there are security concerns when using the above code as well as os.popen being Deprecated since version 2.6. However, for a quick local script in 2.7, the above will suffice.

Comment: print os.popen(r'''C:\wisdem\plugins\JacketSE\src\jacketse\SubDyn\bin\SubDyn_Win32.exe C:\wisdem\plugins\JacketSE\src\jacketse\SubDyn\CertTest\Test04_TrialD3.txt''').read()

Comment: I also tried using subprocess.Popen(r'''C:\wisdem\plugins\JacketSE\src...''') nor subprocess.call(r'''C:\wisdem\plugins\JacketSE\src...'''), and both of them ran the .exe, but neither returned the results to Python. This is discouraging because it seems subprocess is a more modern/robust that os.popen. Nevertheless, I'm grateful for the help!

Comment: `os.popen` uses the shell (cmd.exe) and should be avoided. Use subprocess. Set `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and read `p.stdout`, or use the `subprocess.check_output` convenience function.